# getting Error When I trying to Update CRM 2013SP1 to CRM 2015

Tags: migration, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, threshold

I'm trying to do a CRM migration:

CRM 2011 -> CRM2013SP1 -> CRM 2015 -> CRM2016

everything worked well with the CRM migration from 2011 to 2013 SP1, but with the 2013 SP1 to CRM 2015 I get this error message, could I get some help...  :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdWDK.jpg)

```
enter 13:36:59|Verbose| Current Role = (Id: 0b245a63-9658-4929-98a1-ca7810874f63, Name: Lesender Zugriff)
13:36:59|Verbose| Skipping Inherited Role = (Id: 0b245a63-9658-4929-98a1-ca7810874f63, Name: Lesender Zugriff, ParentRoleId: 3ac7e835-e0b0-e311-8cbb-00155db2fc10)
13:36:59|Verbose| Current Role = (Id: c8e93c48-3171-4492-bfb4-ca801e24ca55, Name: CRM Einstellungen)
13:36:59|Verbose| Skipping Inherited Role = (Id: c8e93c48-3171-4492-bfb4-ca801e24ca55, Name: CRM Einstellungen, ParentRoleId: 9da41221-3be4-4763-a1a7-98e6cf96f7bd)
13:36:59|Verbose| Current Role = (Id: b493b9ed-f7ee-4566-bd97-cac86e8aeba6, Name: Systemanpasser)
13:36:59|Verbose| Skipping Inherited Role = (Id: b493b9ed-f7ee-4566-bd97-cac86e8aeba6, Name: Systemanpasser, ParentRoleId: 7740adee-3832-4a64-99cc-d55880646345)
13:36:59|Verbose| Current Role = (Id: 58ecd193-8f74-4be4-bb03-d2dfef960931, Name: Excel Export)
13:36:59|Verbose| Skipping Inherited Role = (Id: 58ecd193-8f74-4be4-bb03-d2dfef960931, Name: Excel Export, ParentRoleId: 9629be1a-4300-e411-bd62-00155db2fc10)
13:36:59|Verbose| Current Role = (Id: ccbeb0e3-1d53-464f-8763-d2e14eb17d27, Name: Benutzer an&ausschalten)
13:36:59|Verbose| Skipping Inherited Role = (Id: ccbeb0e3-1d53-464f-8763-d2e14eb17d27, Name: Benutzer an&ausschalten, ParentRoleId: c2dae697-7f3c-e111-a725-001b78089c2e)
13:36:59|Verbose| Current Role = (Id: 7740adee-3832-4a64-99cc-d55880646345, Name: Systemanpasser)
13:36:59|Verbose| prvReadSharePointDocument added.
13:36:59|Verbose| prvReadSharePointData added.
13:36:59|Verbose| prvWriteSharePointData added.
13:36:59|Verbose| prvCreateSharePointData added.
13:36:59|Verbose| Error occured: Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.CrmDuplicateRecordException: Cannot insert duplicate key.
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Platform.SolutionAwareComponents.CreateInstanceActionBase.ExecuteCreate(IDbCommand command, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Platform.SolutionAwareComponents.ComponentStateTransition.Execute(Int32 componentType, Guid objectId, Object operationParameter, BusinessComponentState currentState, ISqlExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.DoCreate(IBusinessEntity entity, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.Create(IBusinessEntity entity, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.RoleServiceInternal`1.AddPrivilegesFromCollection(Guid roleId, RolePrivilege[] privileges, Boolean import, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.RoleServiceInternal`1.AddPrivilegesInternal(Guid roleId, RolePrivilege[] privileges, Boolean replace, Boolean import, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.RoleServiceInternal`1.AddPrivileges(Guid roleId, RolePrivilege[] privileges, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.SE.DllMethodActions.UpdateSharePointPrivilegesForExistingRoles.Execute()

13:37:00|   Info| CrmAction execution time; UpgradeDatabaseAction; 00:10:00.1257151
13:37:00|  Error| Installer Complete: OrganizationUpgrader - Error encountered
13:37:00|  Error| Exception occured during Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.OrganizationUpgrader: Error.ActionFailed Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.UpgradeDatabaseAction
InnerException:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Ein Aufrufziel hat einen Ausnahmefehler verursacht. ---> Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.CrmDuplicateRecordException: Cannot insert duplicate key.
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Platform.SolutionAwareComponents.CreateInstanceActionBase.ExecuteCreate(IDbCommand command, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Platform.SolutionAwareComponents.ComponentStateTransition.Execute(Int32 componentType, Guid objectId, Object operationParameter, BusinessComponentState currentState, ISqlExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.DoCreate(IBusinessEntity entity, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.Create(IBusinessEntity entity, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.RoleServiceInternal`1.AddPrivilegesFromCollection(Guid roleId, RolePrivilege[] privileges, Boolean import, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.RoleServiceInternal`1.AddPrivilegesInternal(Guid roleId, RolePrivilege[] privileges, Boolean replace, Boolean import, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.RoleServiceInternal`1.AddPrivileges(Guid roleId, RolePrivilege[] privileges, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.SE.DllMethodActions.UpdateSharePointPrivilegesForExistingRoles.Execute()
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   bei System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DllMethodAction.Execute(Guid organizationId)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DatabaseInstaller.ExecuteReleases(ReleaseInfo releaseInfo, Boolean isInstall)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DatabaseInstaller.Install(Int32 languageCode, String configurationFilePath, Boolean upgradeDatabase, Boolean isInstall)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DatabaseInstaller.Install(Int32 languageCode, String configurationFilePath, Boolean upgradeDatabase)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.InstallDatabaseAction.Do(IDictionary parameters)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.CrmAction.ExecuteAction(CrmAction action, IDictionary parameters, Boolean undo)
InnerException:
Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.CrmDuplicateRecordException: Cannot insert duplicate key.
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Platform.SolutionAwareComponents.CreateInstanceActionBase.ExecuteCreate(IDbCommand command, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Platform.SolutionAwareComponents.ComponentStateTransition.Execute(Int32 componentType, Guid objectId, Object operationParameter, BusinessComponentState currentState, ISqlExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.DoCreate(IBusinessEntity entity, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.Create(IBusinessEntity entity, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.RoleServiceInternal`1.AddPrivilegesFromCollection(Guid roleId, RolePrivilege[] privileges, Boolean import, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.RoleServiceInternal`1.AddPrivilegesInternal(Guid roleId, RolePrivilege[] privileges, Boolean replace, Boolean import, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.RoleServiceInternal`1.AddPrivileges(Guid roleId, RolePrivilege[] privileges, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.SE.DllMethodActions.UpdateSharePointPrivilegesForExistingRoles.Execute()

13:37:00|   Info| Setting organization state.  New state = Failed
13:37:00|  Error| Fehler beim Upgraden der Organisation mit der ID "1a5793aa-339d-e111-8c6b-00155db2fc0d". Ausnahme:
System.Exception: Error.ActionFailed Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.UpgradeDatabaseAction ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Ein Aufrufziel hat einen Ausnahmefehler verursacht. ---> Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.CrmDuplicateRecordException: Cannot insert duplicate key.
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Platform.SolutionAwareComponents.CreateInstanceActionBase.ExecuteCreate(IDbCommand command, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Platform.SolutionAwareComponents.ComponentStateTransition.Execute(Int32 componentType, Guid objectId, Object operationParameter, BusinessComponentState currentState, ISqlExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.DoCreate(IBusinessEntity entity, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.Create(IBusinessEntity entity, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.RoleServiceInternal`1.AddPrivilegesFromCollection(Guid roleId, RolePrivilege[] privileges, Boolean import, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.RoleServiceInternal`1.AddPrivilegesInternal(Guid roleId, RolePrivilege[] privileges, Boolean replace, Boolean import, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.RoleServiceInternal`1.AddPrivileges(Guid roleId, RolePrivilege[] privileges, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.SE.DllMethodActions.UpdateSharePointPrivilegesForExistingRoles.Execute()
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   bei System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DllMethodAction.Execute(Guid organizationId)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DatabaseInstaller.ExecuteReleases(ReleaseInfo releaseInfo, Boolean isInstall)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DatabaseInstaller.Install(Int32 languageCode, String configurationFilePath, Boolean upgradeDatabase, Boolean isInstall)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DatabaseInstaller.Install(Int32 languageCode, String configurationFilePath, Boolean upgradeDatabase)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.InstallDatabaseAction.Do(IDictionary parameters)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.CrmAction.ExecuteAction(CrmAction action, IDictionary parameters, Boolean undo)
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.CrmAction.ExecuteAction(CrmAction action, IDictionary parameters, Boolean undo)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.Installer.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.OrganizationOperation.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.OrganizationUpgrader.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.OrganizationOperation.Execute()
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.ImportOrganizationInstaller.ImportAndUpgrade(OrganizationInfo organizationInfo)
13:37:00|  Error| An error occurred when trying import and upgrade organization database SVMCONSULT001.Cobra_Music_MSCRM:
Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: Fehler beim Upgraden der Organisation mit der ID "1a5793aa-339d-e111-8c6b-00155db2fc0d". Ausnahme:
System.Exception: Error.ActionFailed Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.UpgradeDatabaseAction ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Ein Aufrufziel hat einen Ausnahmefehler verursacht. ---> Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.CrmDuplicateRecordException: Cannot insert duplicate key.
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Platform.SolutionAwareComponents.CreateInstanceActionBase.ExecuteCreate(IDbCommand command, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Platform.SolutionAwareComponents.ComponentStateTransition.Execute(Int32 componentType, Guid objectId, Object operationParameter, BusinessComponentState currentState, ISqlExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.DoCreate(IBusinessEntity entity, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.Create(IBusinessEntity entity, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.RoleServiceInternal`1.AddPrivilegesFromCollection(Guid roleId, RolePrivilege[] privileges, Boolean import, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.RoleServiceInternal`1.AddPrivilegesInternal(Guid roleId, RolePrivilege[] privileges, Boolean replace, Boolean import, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.RoleServiceInternal`1.AddPrivileges(Guid roleId, RolePrivilege[] privileges, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.SE.DllMethodActions.UpdateSharePointPrivilegesForExistingRoles.Execute()
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   bei System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DllMethodAction.Execute(Guid organizationId)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DatabaseInstaller.ExecuteReleases(ReleaseInfo releaseInfo, Boolean isInstall)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DatabaseInstaller.Install(Int32 languageCode, String configurationFilePath, Boolean upgradeDatabase, Boolean isInstall)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DatabaseInstaller.Install(Int32 languageCode, String configurationFilePath, Boolean upgradeDatabase)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.InstallDatabaseAction.Do(IDictionary parameters)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.CrmAction.ExecuteAction(CrmAction action, IDictionary parameters, Boolean undo)
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.CrmAction.ExecuteAction(CrmAction action, IDictionary parameters, Boolean undo)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.Installer.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.OrganizationOperation.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.OrganizationUpgrader.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.OrganizationOperation.Execute()
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.ImportOrganizationInstaller.ImportAndUpgrade(OrganizationInfo organizationInfo) ---> System.Exception: Error.ActionFailed Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.UpgradeDatabaseAction ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Ein Aufrufziel hat einen Ausnahmefehler verursacht. ---> Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.CrmDuplicateRecordException: Cannot insert duplicate key.
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Platform.SolutionAwareComponents.CreateInstanceActionBase.ExecuteCreate(IDbCommand command, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Platform.SolutionAwareComponents.ComponentStateTransition.Execute(Int32 componentType, Guid objectId, Object operationParameter, BusinessComponentState currentState, ISqlExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.DoCreate(IBusinessEntity entity, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.Create(IBusinessEntity entity, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.RoleServiceInternal`1.AddPrivilegesFromCollection(Guid roleId, RolePrivilege[] privileges, Boolean import, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.RoleServiceInternal`1.AddPrivilegesInternal(Guid roleId, RolePrivilege[] privileges, Boolean replace, Boolean import, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.RoleServiceInternal`1.AddPrivileges(Guid roleId, RolePrivilege[] privileges, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.SE.DllMethodActions.UpdateSharePointPrivilegesForExistingRoles.Execute()
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   bei System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DllMethodAction.Execute(Guid organizationId)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DatabaseInstaller.ExecuteReleases(ReleaseInfo releaseInfo, Boolean isInstall)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DatabaseInstaller.Install(Int32 languageCode, String configurationFilePath, Boolean upgradeDatabase, Boolean isInstall)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DatabaseInstaller.Install(Int32 languageCode, String configurationFilePath, Boolean upgradeDatabase)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.InstallDatabaseAction.Do(IDictionary parameters)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.CrmAction.ExecuteAction(CrmAction action, IDictionary parameters, Boolean undo)
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.CrmAction.ExecuteAction(CrmAction action, IDictionary parameters, Boolean undo)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.Installer.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.OrganizationOperation.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.OrganizationUpgrader.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.OrganizationOperation.Execute()
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.ImportOrganizationInstaller.ImportAndUpgrade(OrganizationInfo organizationInfo)
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.ImportOrganizationInstaller.ImportAndUpgrade(OrganizationInfo organizationInfo)
13:37:00|  Error| Ausnahmefehler beim Importieren der Organisation (Name=CobraMusic, Id=1a5793aa-339d-e111-8c6b-00155db2fc0d):
Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: Fehler beim Upgraden der Organisation mit der ID "1a5793aa-339d-e111-8c6b-00155db2fc0d". Ausnahme:
System.Exception: Error.ActionFailed Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.UpgradeDatabaseAction ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Ein Aufrufziel hat einen Ausnahmefehler verursacht. ---> Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.CrmDuplicateRecordException: Cannot insert duplicate key.
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Platform.SolutionAwareComponents.CreateInstanceActionBase.ExecuteCreate(IDbCommand command, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Platform.SolutionAwareComponents.ComponentStateTransition.Execute(Int32 componentType, Guid objectId, Object operationParameter, BusinessComponentState currentState, ISqlExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.DoCreate(IBusinessEntity entity, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.Create(IBusinessEntity entity, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.RoleServiceInternal`1.AddPrivilegesFromCollection(Guid roleId, RolePrivilege[] privileges, Boolean import, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.RoleServiceInternal`1.AddPrivilegesInternal(Guid roleId, RolePrivilege[] privileges, Boolean replace, Boolean import, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.RoleServiceInternal`1.AddPrivileges(Guid roleId, RolePrivilege[] privileges, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.SE.DllMethodActions.UpdateSharePointPrivilegesForExistingRoles.Execute()
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   bei System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DllMethodAction.Execute(Guid organizationId)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DatabaseInstaller.ExecuteReleases(ReleaseInfo releaseInfo, Boolean isInstall)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DatabaseInstaller.Install(Int32 languageCode, String configurationFilePath, Boolean upgradeDatabase, Boolean isInstall)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DatabaseInstaller.Install(Int32 languageCode, String configurationFilePath, Boolean upgradeDatabase)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.InstallDatabaseAction.Do(IDictionary parameters)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.CrmAction.ExecuteAction(CrmAction action, IDictionary parameters, Boolean undo)
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.CrmAction.ExecuteAction(CrmAction action, IDictionary parameters, Boolean undo)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.Installer.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.OrganizationOperation.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.OrganizationUpgrader.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.OrganizationOperation.Execute()
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.ImportOrganizationInstaller.ImportAndUpgrade(OrganizationInfo organizationInfo) ---> System.Exception: Error.ActionFailed Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.UpgradeDatabaseAction ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Ein Aufrufziel hat einen Ausnahmefehler verursacht. ---> Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.CrmDuplicateRecordException: Cannot insert duplicate key.
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Platform.SolutionAwareComponents.CreateInstanceActionBase.ExecuteCreate(IDbCommand command, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Platform.SolutionAwareComponents.ComponentStateTransition.Execute(Int32 componentType, Guid objectId, Object operationParameter, BusinessComponentState currentState, ISqlExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.DoCreate(IBusinessEntity entity, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.Create(IBusinessEntity entity, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.RoleServiceInternal`1.AddPrivilegesFromCollection(Guid roleId, RolePrivilege[] privileges, Boolean import, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.RoleServiceInternal`1.AddPrivilegesInternal(Guid roleId, RolePrivilege[] privileges, Boolean replace, Boolean import, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.RoleServiceInternal`1.AddPrivileges(Guid roleId, RolePrivilege[] privileges, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.SE.DllMethodActions.UpdateSharePointPrivilegesForExistingRoles.Execute()
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   bei System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DllMethodAction.Execute(Guid organizationId)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DatabaseInstaller.ExecuteReleases(ReleaseInfo releaseInfo, Boolean isInstall)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DatabaseInstaller.Install(Int32 languageCode, String configurationFilePath, Boolean upgradeDatabase, Boolean isInstall)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DatabaseInstaller.Install(Int32 languageCode, String configurationFilePath, Boolean upgradeDatabase)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.InstallDatabaseAction.Do(IDictionary parameters)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.CrmAction.ExecuteAction(CrmAction action, IDictionary parameters, Boolean undo)
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.CrmAction.ExecuteAction(CrmAction action, IDictionary parameters, Boolean undo)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.Installer.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.OrganizationOperation.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.OrganizationUpgrader.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.OrganizationOperation.Execute()
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.ImportOrganizationInstaller.ImportAndUpgrade(OrganizationInfo organizationInfo)
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.ImportOrganizationInstaller.ImportAndUpgrade(OrganizationInfo organizationInfo)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.ImportOrganizationInstaller.Execute(Object obj)
13:37:00|   Info| Found the older table DBUpdateInstallInfo_V5, updating new table and deleting
13:37:00|   Info| GetDBUpdateRevisionThresholdForServer(): Threshold = 7.0.0000.3543.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says : Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.CrmDuplicateRecordException: Cannot insert duplicate key.
Which means you might have already same records in the current environment where you are trying to upgrade, either you have to turn off the duplicity check or delete those records before trying to migrate.
1- To turn off Duplicate check go to : Settings-->Data Management -->Duplicate Detection Settings.
2- Best practice is also to disable plugins/custom workflow activities during a migration.

---

If it is just a solution migration with no records, check if you have any duplicate of Option Sets from imported solution to current environment, unique Entities etc.